# Error after nvidia driver install Fedora 31

Tags: fedora, nvidia

I have an MSI GT70 that I recently installed Fedora 31 on. 
I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 870M on board and I installed the Nvidia drivers using the RPM fusion method found [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-fedora-31)
Once installed every time I reboot I get an error of :

```
"Failed To Update": Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.fwupd: Timeout was reached.
```

I have also noted that I have an additional boot option of:
Fedora (5.3.7-301)
as well as Fedora (5.3.13-300).

Three questions:
What is causing this error?

How do I fix this error?

and lastly why the new boot option?

Comment: You have two boot options because the kernel was upgraded when you ran `dnf update` in the instructions. Those options are for the new one and the old one.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's probably `tpm2-abrmd` as discussed in [Bug 1731758 - Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.fwupd: Timeout was reached](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1731758).
2. Try removing `tpm2-abrmd` (not recommend) or wait for it to be upgraded to 2.3.1.
3. You might try this to control it in your way: [YUM/DNF Remove Old Kernels on Fedora/CentOS/RHEL](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/delete-remove-old-kernels-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/).